# How to force a deep copy when copying structs with arrays?

Tags: c#

If have a

```
struct A {
  public double[] Data;
  public int X;
}
```

How can I force a deep copy when using `operator=` or adding instances of `A` to a container?

The problem is for example:

```
A a = new A();
var list = new List<A>();
list.Add(a); // does not make a deep copy of Data
A b = a; // does not make a deep copy of Data
```

Do I really have to implement my own `DeepClone` method and call it every time? This would be extremly error-prone ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should avoid putting mutable reference types like Array into structs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945664/can-structs-contain-references-to-reference-types-in-c) and answer.

So make your class a reference type and give it a DeepCopy method. Or even better - make your type immutable so that you don't need to make a copy.

Comment: +1: It's good to keep simple classes immutable, if you can, as it reduces the possibility for error when using them.  For instance, even if you implement a Deep Copy, there is no guarantee that the consumer of your code will actually use it.  With structs, in particular, mutability is quite unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the deep copy method yourself.

Quite often API designers design a *Clone()*, *Clone(bool deep)*, or *Copy()* method to do this.

*ICloneable* is used sometimes to mark class is cloneable, but it can be confusing since it doesn't specify if the Clone() method is deep or shallow.  [Why should I implement ICloneable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that.  You need to implement your own deep copy mechanism.