# Assign numeric value to class

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Overloading assignment operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537803/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c-sharp)

I remember I saw this question somewhere in stack overflow but I cannot find it.

Basically I will like to be able to do:

```
MyClass myClass = 5;
```

where MyClass is a class implemented by my program.

I will delete this question if I can find that duplicate.

Comment: Kids , instead of downvoting , teach him.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It looks confusing as hell.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Prepare to be serial upvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want an implicit cast operator.

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(int m) 
{
     // code to convert from int to MyClass
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `implicit` operator.

[MSDN implicit (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    private MyClass(int i)
    {
        MyProperty = i;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyClass(int x)
    {
        return new MyClass(x);
    }
}

MyClass myClass = 5;
```