# Initialize object by assignment?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, initialization, variable-assignment

How to give types the ability to initialize via an assignment, some like the following:

```
public struct WrappedByte
{
    private byte m_value;
}

//Usage:    
WrappedByte x = 0xFF;
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537803/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a custom implicit operator.  Note that this doesn't just apply to structs.

```
public struct WrappedByte
{
    private byte m_value;

    public static implicit operator WrappedByte(byte b)
    {
        return new WrappedByte() { m_value = b };
    }
}
```

Also note that this won't apply just to initialization; it will mean that you can supply a `byte` in any location that a `WrappedByte` is expected.  It also includes assignments other than initializations, parameters to methods, etc.