# How to overloaded unary operator = in c#. it is giving error

Tags: c#-4.0

Unable to overloaded unary operator = in c#. it is giving error.

```
public static Result operator =(Int32 iv)
{
    return new Result(){iv=iv};
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a use-case would help. As it stands there is only one correct answer: you can't. If we knew how/why you were planning on using this, we might be able to offer better methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload the `=` operator in C#.

From [7.2.2 Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324.aspx):

> In particular, it is not possible to overload member access, method invocation, or the `=`, `&&`, `||`, `?:`, `checked`, `unchecked`, `new`, `typeof`, `as`, and `is` operators.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overload the assignment operator in C#.

However, there is a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537803/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c-sharp).