# How can I do direct assignment without using new?

Tags: c#, assign

I would like to do something like this in C#:

```
Foo test = "string";
```

And now the object should be initialized. How can I achieve that? I can't get it to work but I know it is possible.

Comment: Answer is here: [Overloading assignment operator in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4537848/754376)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for an implicit conversion operator.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Foo(string s)
    {
        return new Foo() { Bar = s };
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Foo f = "asdf";
Console.WriteLine(f.Bar); // yields => "asdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast operator to implicitly:

```
sealed class Foo
{
    public string Str
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    Foo()
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo(string str)
    {
        return new Foo
        {
            Str = str
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can do `Foo test = "string";`.

Comment: +1 but you should fix the syntax error in your answer. (`Str` does not exist)