# Way to have a class Schedule behaving like List<DateTime>?

Tags: c#

I have:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public List<DateTime> Dates {get; set;}

// Some methods
}
```

I'd like Schedule to behave as List:

```
var date = Schedule[idx];
dates = List<DateTime>;
Schedule = dates;
dates = Schedule;
...
```

Schedule should be a list of Dates as it is in reality, by adding a member Dates, it feels like a computer object, adding a layer of abstraction and moving away from the modeled object.

There are 2 possibilities but they are not perfect:

Overloading operators (e.g. "[]") but "="can't be overloaded.

Alias with "using" but it won't have any method.

For example, in C++, I would have overloaded the operators and keep a private member _dates.

Thanks

Comment: "Schedule should be a list of Dates as it is in reality, by adding a member Dates, it feels like a computer object, adding a layer of abstraction and moving away from the modeled object." ... What? Huh?

Comment: Assuming your actual question is about getting `Schedule = dates` to work - covered in existing ["Overloading assignment operator in C#"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537803/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c-sharp). If you mean something else - please clarify how your requirement is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Schedule **IS** a list of dates, then make it one:

```
public class Schedule : List<DateTime>
{
   // More stuff
}

Schedule MySchedule = new Schedule();

MySchedule.Add(DateTime.Now);
```