# Passing struct into function which accepts object

Tags: c#, struct, reference

If we have a struct and a class they will be passed differently if you call a function with them as parameter.

```
struct MyStruct{}
class MyClass{}

// s is a value (struct) which passed by value
private void WriteStruct(MyStruct s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// c is a reference to an class-instance which is passed by value
private void WriteClass(MyClass c)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

This behaviour is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters).

Now what happens if we have a function which accepts `object`.

```
private void Write(object obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

I'm aware of [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) and assume that it'll just be boxed implicitly but I'm unsure in this case, mostly because `ValueType` inherits from `Object` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype)) and also because I don't see why it wouldn't just be passed as is without any boxing since that obviously works (at least) when the signature also uses that struct.

**Will calling this method with a struct (or any other value type) box the struct and actually pass a reference or will the struct itself be passed?**

Ps. I don't know how you could test this because if you were to cast it to the struct in the function, a new struct would be created<sup>1</sup> and the reference (if there was one) would be lost anyway. Thats why the following code doesn't change the value no matter how `obj` was passed.

```
private static void ChangeObj(object obj)
{
    var s = (MyStruct)obj; // this will create a new struct
    s.MyInt = 400;
} // s is now lost, the passed in value is unchanged
```

#### EDIT:

TheGeneral mentioned in the comments to head over to sharplab. I have no clue about IL but when looking at the following code, I can see some interesting differences.

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct();
MyClass c = new MyClass();

WriteStruct(s);
WriteClass(c);

Write(s);
```

- The `WriteStruct(s)` instruction contains an IL instruction `call instance void Test::WriteStruct(valuetype MyStruct)` (and some other stuff I don't get).
- The `WriteClass(c)` instruction contains an IL instruction `call instance void Test::WriteClass(class MyClass)` (and some other stuff I don't get).
- The `Write(s)` instruction (drumroll) contains an IL instruction `box MyStruct` (woo) followed by `call instance void Test::Write(object)`

I guess this means the value is indeed boxed.. Is there anything to add to this?
I'm guessing it has to be boxed since the runtime treats all `object`s which are explicitly marked as `object` as references, is that correct?
If so, why is there this `class` keyword in the signature of the IL-`call instance` instruction when calling `WriteClass` but not when calling `Write`? There's just `object` without any `class` or `valuetype` keyword. Is this too much of implementation details and IL-gibbrish (btw IL looks cool, might look into that more) to include in an answer here or is it possible to explain this in an easy way?

---

<sup>1</sup> Talking about *creating* might be wrong here since the values are just copied. MSDN says in the [boxing-unboxing-article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing): *Copying the value from the instance into the value-type variable.*

Comment: https://sharplab.io/ check if it boxes for your self

Comment: Sadly I have absolutely no clue about IL.. But I'll look into it thanks :)

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral, I got a good start :) Please see my edit

Comment: Most probably, it will create a boxed local copy of your struct and then pass-by-value a reference to the locally created object. Can I ask you what are you trying to achieve? The general rule is that structs are always treated as values.

Comment: This may be the one instance of a "type keyword" in the IL language. The alternative would've been `class System.Object`. Keep in mind that IL is just a textual representation of the underlying binary code. As a comparison, in 16-bit x86 assembly, the instruction `mov ax, 0` is `B8 00 00`, but if I wanted to write another assembler where `cp 0 -> #ax` results in the same three bytes, that would be just as good. For *learning* purposes, try not to put too much value in *how* it's represented and put more into *what* is being represented.

Comment: That said, for *production* purposes, representation is very important because it can make maintenance easier or harder depending on how clearly you write something.

Comment: It probably should be noted that, structs really should be immutable

Comment: @LucioM.Tato Trying to achieve might be the wrong word. I'm trying to write a pro-cons list for using `struct` in a certain scenario. Initially I used `struct` because it has value semantics and doesn't need any inheritance. However I found that there are almost no benefits in my case. One thing I wasn't sure about is if there is a theoretical performance hit because it will be passed into a function as an object. I now know this does in fact box the value and give me a small performance penalty. In my case this really wouldn't matter but I didn't want to say anything wrong.

Comment: @madreflection I know what IL is but again, don't know anything about how to read it (I have not gone that low-level yet). I don't quite understand what you mean by _production purposes_. You said the _representation_ is important there but what _production_ and what _representation_ (my code, the IL, the actual bytes) do you mean?

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes I know that this is one of the most important guidelines. This is also one of the reasons I think not using `struct` and just going with `class` is better in my case (it can contain a mutable reference type and that's not very desirable for an immutable struct, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945708/10883465)).

Comment: By "production", I simply meant *producing* or writing code in an actual product, for which the previous comment's advice would have been wrong. My point is that how IL represents `object` is inconsequential. It's `object`. You're asking about a special case in representation but your question reads as if you're trying to find some meaning in it and there's not.

Comment: You asked *"why is there this `class` keyword in the signature of the IL-call instance instruction when calling `WriteClass` but not when calling `Write`?"* I'm saying that `object` in the signature of `Write` might as well be `class System.Object` and don't read too much into that. I could ask the same thing about C, which requires `struct` before the type name *everywhere* you use it. That's just how the language was designed. C++ relaxed that requirement. C could have relaxed it but didn't.