# How does .Net understand nested valuetypes? Are they valuetypes?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, value-type

In situations like this:

```
public struct SectorLocator
{
    public Surface Side { get; init; } //this is an enum-int

    public VerticalPortion Section { get; init; } //this is another enum-int
}


public struct DataLocator
{

    public SectorLocator Sector{get; init;}

    public MeasureType Measure { get; init; } //this is another enum-int;

}
```

is DataLocator still a value-type? Or it's like when you put a reference type inside a struct?
How does Sector property behave when you pass it as an argument?

I didn't found any answer clear enough about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can structs contain fields of reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945664/can-structs-contain-fields-of-reference-types)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so. My question is about how SectorLocator property is handled. Is a reference? or is it still a value type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DataLocator` is still a value-type; that is defined fully from the `struct` term. A value-type can *contain* references, but that doesn't change anything about how it behaves, other than: you're not allowed to use it in an `unmanaged` constraint if it does contain references (and some APIs like `Unsafe`/`MemoryMarshal` etc may refuse to play with you). This is effectively the same as asking `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferences<T>()`: this will return `false` for a value-type that *does not* contain references, and `true` for any other scenario.

Comment: But that SectorLocator property inside DataLocator is a reference or is a raw value? That's my question. I know is irrelevant because are init-only, but I want to learn and know more.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper `SectorLocator` is a value-type, so `DataLocator` literally contains the *value* of `SectorLocator`; if `SectorLocator` takes 20 bytes, then `DataLocator` will presumably be 24 (4 bytes for the integer) (plus padding if needed). A non-boxed reference to a `SectorLocator` is a `ref SectorLocator`, and you can't store that in fields of either a class or a struct, except *sort of* in a `ref struct`, via a *span*.

Comment: @MarkGravell That's the answer I want to hear. Sorry if the question was unprecise. Thank you so much.